# Spring.Net TypeLoadException when .exe and .Config files are renamed

Tags: c#, .net, spring.net

I've built an application using Spring.Net.  I've run into a scenario where it is necessary to rename the executable.  I thought the easiest way would be to rename the .exe and its .config file, however this causes a `TypeLoadException` during `ContextRegistry.GetContext()`.

Here's a look at the structure:

```
-Release
|-Library.dll
|-MyApp.exe
|-MyApp.exe.Config
|-SpringConfigFile.xml
```

And within the SpringConfigFile I have:

```
<object id="ObjFromLibrary" type="Library.SomeType, Library">
  <!-- properties go here -->
</object>

<object id="ObjFromMyApp" type="MyApp.SomeOtherType, MyApp">
  <!-- properties -->
</object>
```

(Of course, this is simplified and I have many objects whose type derives from the `MyApp` assembly)

The exception reads:

`Error creating context 'spring.root': Could not load type from string value 'MyApp.SomeOtherType, MyApp'. ---> Spring.Core.CannotLoadObjectTypeException: Cannot resolve type [MyApp.SomeOtherType, MyApp] for object with name 'ObjFromMyApp' defined in file Release\SpringConfigFile.xml] line 5 ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type from string value 'MyApp.SomeOtherType, MyApp'.`

Which basically indicates Spring had no problem creating the object `ObjectFromLibrary`, but failed on `ObjFromMyApp` (in my "real-world" application, `ObjFromMyApp` is the first object dependent on `MyApp` and not another dll)

My question is, is there a way to *easily* rename this .exe and not have Spring fail to load?  I know I could rebuild the project with a new name and refactor the `SpringConfigFile.xml` to use the new assembly, but I'd prefer to do it without a rebuild.  If this requires refactoring the project once so that I can rename it later, that would be acceptable as well.

Another more philosophical question is, should I expect renaming an .exe file to cause a .NET program to stop working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know I could rebuild the project with a new name and refactor the
>   SpringConfigFile.xml to use the new assembly, but I'd prefer to do it
>   without a rebuild.

You don't need to rebuild the project. Only modify the contents of SpringConfigFile.xml so that it uses the new name of the assembly.

> Another more philosophical question is, should I expect renaming an
>   .exe file to cause a .NET program to stop working?

This would entirely depend on how this program is designed and what it is doing. As you have already discovered in your case Spring.NET uses runtime binding to the actual type and if the assembly in which this type is declared is modified it will break the configuration.

So basically you will need to perform the update of the xml configuration file and the rename of the executable at the same time.

I am not sure whether Spring.NET supports fluent API to configure your container but some other DI frameworks such as Ninject certainly do and are more stable to such renames because the container setup is made with code instead of some weakly typed magic strings XMLs.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I thought. In this case, I'm going to most likely rebuild the assembly under a different name, since I can use tools like R# to help me rename the huge number of assembly referencing strings in my actual SpringConfigFile.xml